# Trouble with a C program

Tags: c

I had a homework. The condition was: "Make a program in witch will be displayed how many 'A' and 'B' where typed". I tried and this is what i made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, a=0, b=0;
    char cr;
    
    scanf ("%i", &n);
    
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {scanf ("%c", &cr); if (cr='A') a++; else if (cr=='B') b++;}
    
    printf ("A-%i\n", a);
    printf ("B-%i", b);
}
```

The problem is when i type for example 10, it only lets me type 5 characters, not 10. Why?
The program can be made with for, while or do while.

Comment: Because you are also entering newline characters. Asides: there is a typo in `if(cr='A')` which you avoided with `if(cr=='B')`, and you are off-by-one with `for (i=0; i<=n; i++)`

Comment: Thx for helping!

Comment: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: @DaNyel Use scanf (" %c", &cr); See the blank before the conversion specifier %c

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems and solutions

- you need to use `scanf(" %c", %cr)` to prevent the program from reading trailing whitespaces
- You should be using `if (cr == 'A')` and not `if (cr = 'A')` because you are comparing and not assigning
- the loop should be `for (i = 0; i < n...` not `for (i = 0; i <= n..` as the loop would ask for 1+ input from the specified range

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, a = 0, b = 0;
    char cr;
    printf("Enter number of tries :\n");
    scanf ("%i", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter char\n");
        scanf(" %c", &cr); 
        if (cr == 'A') a++; 
        else if (cr == 'B') b++;
    }
    printf ("A-%i\n", a);
    printf ("B-%i", b);
}
```

Comment: I knew about `if (cr='A')` but i forgot about it when i was trying to find the mistake.

Comment: @DaNyel ah i see happens, happy coding ;)

Comment: Thanks @AnanthDev